# Fatal error: cannot create R_TempDir (Installing R package in Ubuntu)

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, tmp

I am trying to install devtools on Ubuntu 16.04 R. I have been able to install several packages, but currently, in my R session, when I type:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

I receive:

```
Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir'
```

Upon issuing the `tempdir()` command in R, I see that my temporary directory is located at `tmp/RtmpD54Esf`. I tried: `rm -r tmp/RtmpD54Esf`. But the problem remains.

I also tried `df -h` which results in:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  9.7M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sdc2        54G   52G  4.6M 100% /
tmpfs            32G  1.8M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       2.7T  1.7T  945G  64% /mnt/disk3
/dev/sdb1       2.7T   73M  2.6T   1% /mnt/disk4
/dev/sdf1       2.7T  2.2T  397G  85% /mnt/disk2
/dev/sde1       2.7T  1.9T  683G  74% /mnt/disk1
/dev/sdc1       511M  4.7M  507M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           6.3G   40K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1004
```

I am not sure if the problem is that `/dev/sdc2` is full. It appears to not be a directory. I tried `sudo umount -f /dev/sdc2` and `sudo umount -l /dev/sdc2` but still the problem persisted.

I have searched for several hours but most suggestions to fix this error revolve around erasing contents in the temp directory and unmounting the largest space from `df -h`. I feel I have tried both these suggestions and am still seeing the error. I do not have lots of Linux management experience and was hoping that by asking this question and following advice very carefully, I can identify if I may be misinterpreting the advice usually available. Thank you for your suggestions!